# Using onclick in javascript to create a new div inside a div created using onclick itself?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a div consisting of radio button inputs using onclick  from a radio button input inside a form in php and then i again attempted to create another div using onclick from inside this created div but only the outer div is being created. Would like to know where i am wrong..

```
        <input id="sub"  type="radio" name="opt1" value="2" onclick="createDiv4()"> Academic User<br/>

           function createDiv4() {
            if(document.getElementById("acad_")==null)
            {
               var divi = document.createElement("div");
               divi.id="acad_";
                divi.style.height="100px";
                //divi.style.marginTop="200px";
               var cont = document.getElementById('contain');
                 cont.appendChild(divi);                   
                var p = document.createElement("label");
               var disp = document.createTextNode("Please select the type of User :");

               p.appendChild(disp);
               p.style.textSize="16px";
               p.style.textAlign="left";
               divi.appendChild(p);
               var b1 = document.createElement("BR");
               divi.appendChild(b1);

               var ip = document.createElement("input");
               ip.name="wo";
               ip.value="1";
               ip.type="radio";
               ip.onclick="createDiv4_1()";
               ip.style.marginRight="4px";

               divi.appendChild(ip);
               var labe = document.createElement("label");

               var labe_val = document.createTextNode("Technical Institute");
               labe.appendChild(labe_val);
               divi.appendChild(labe);

               var b = document.createElement("BR");
               divi.appendChild(b);

               var ip2 = document.createElement("input");
               ip2.name="wo";
               ip2.value="2";
               ip2.type="radio";
               ip2.style.marginRight="4px";
               ip2.onclick="createDiv4_1()";
               divi.appendChild(ip2);

                var labe2 = document.createElement("label");

               var labe_val2 = document.createTextNode("School");
               labe2.appendChild(labe_val2);
               divi.appendChild(labe2);


                if(document.getElementById("govt")!=null)
               {
                   var de = document.getElementById("govt");
                   de.parentNode.removeChild(de);
               }

            }   
            else
            {
                var divi1 = document.getElementById("acad_");
                divi1.parentNode.removeChild(divi1);
            }
        }

    </script>
    <script>    
        function createDiv4_1() {
            if(document.getElementById("school")==null)
            {

               var divi = document.createElement("div");
               divi.id="school";

                //divi.style.marginTop="200px";
               var cont = document.getElementById('contain');
                 cont.appendChild(divi);                   
                var p = document.createElement("label");
               var disp = document.createTextNode("Please select the type of User for  Workshop :");

               p.appendChild(disp);
               p.style.textSize="16px";
               p.style.textAlign="left";
               divi.appendChild(p);
               var b1 = document.createElement("BR");
               divi.appendChild(b1);

               var ip = document.createElement("input");
                ip.name="wo";
               ip.value="1";
               ip.type="radio";
               ip.style.marginRight="4px";

               divi.appendChild(ip);
               var labe = document.createElement("label");

               var labe_val = document.createTextNode("School Student");
               labe.appendChild(labe_val);
               divi.appendChild(labe);

               var b = document.createElement("BR");
               divi.appendChild(b);

               var ip2 = document.createElement("input");
               ip2.name="wo";
               ip2.value="2";
               ip2.type="radio";
               ip2.style.marginRight="4px";

               divi.appendChild(ip2);

                var labe2 = document.createElement("label");

               var labe_val2 = document.createTextNode("Teacher");
               labe2.appendChild(labe_val2);
               divi.appendChild(labe2);

               var b2 = document.createElement("BR");
                divi.appendChild(b2);

                var ip2 = document.createElement("input");
               ip2.name="wo";
               ip2.value="2";
               ip2.type="radio";
               ip2.style.marginRight="4px";

               divi.appendChild(ip2);

                var labe3 = document.createElement("label");

               var labe_val3 = document.createTextNode("Parent");
               labe3.appendChild(labe_val3);
               divi.appendChild(labe3);

                if(document.getElementById("govt")!=null)
               {
                   var de = document.getElementById("govt");
                   de.parentNode.removeChild(de);
               }

            }   
            else
            {
                var divi1 = document.getElementById("school");
                divi1.parentNode.removeChild(divi1);
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent calling the functions properly. Instead of :

```
ip.onclick= "createDiv4_1()";
```

This is only a string, it won't call it. You put it in quotes in the HTML but in JavaScript you don't need to. Also get rid of the parenthesis in JS. So use this :

```
ip.onclick= createDiv4_1;
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/xgvqwcq4/2/

I added a div with ID `contain` for this to work too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion it worked correctly. Actually this is the first time I am using js so syntax is a little unclear. But there is still 1 problem .. when i am clicking on a radio button in div with id school (the inner one) the radio button input of the div with id acad_ is not showing . Can you please explain why.

Comment: When you click the technical institute button it shows(creates) the div, if you then click the school button it removes this div as the div with ID school has been created. Check your if statement on like 71.

Comment: That is okay but how is this related to the radio button of the outer div (id="acad_") not showing any input ? Whether the div with id="school " (inner one) is created or not the radio button input of the outer one (id="acad_") should still remain intact right?

Answer (score -1):

according to your question title you have two option.

forget about onclikc inside the html and use normal js

```
document.getElementById("secondDiv").addEventListener("click", function () {
    newFunctionI();
})


/*JQ version*/
$("#secondDiv").on("click", function () {
     newFunctionI();
})
```

second way is: use jquery append() or html();

```
function yourFunctionI() {
    $("#ID").append("<div id='secondDiv' onclick='newFunction()'> new </div>")
}
```